# How to use image into jquery pagination plugin

Tags: jquery

I use "simplePagination" plugin http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/#page-9. I do not know how to implement image insertion to this plugin. My intent is that in every page there will be shown one image. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is unclear. Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried and explain the issues you're having with the code

Comment: As I read the documentation, you should use the `onPageClick`-event to show the appropiate image. How you have to do that exactly, depends highly on your current HTML and image-locations. Since you didn't provide any at all (nor what you have tried already), we can't help you any further right now.

Comment: Thanks Peter van der Wal. I solve this problem.